# How can I Use RabbitMQ between two application while I can't change one of them?

Tags: rabbitmq, message-queue

I have an existing system consisting of two nodes, a client/server model.
I want to exchange messages between them using RabbitMQ. I.e. The client would send all its requests to RabbitMQ and the server would listen to the queue indefinitely, consume any messages that arrives and then act upon it.

I can change the server as needed, but my problem is, I cannot change the client's behavior. How can I send back the response to the client?

The client node understands HTTP request/response, what shall I do after configure the other application server to RabbitMQ instead of my app directly.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [RPC model](http://www.rabbitmq.com/tutorials/tutorial-six-java.html) or some internal convention, like storing result in database (or cache) with known id and polling your storage for that result in a cycle

Answer (score 0):

You will have to use a proxy server in between that will seem to node 1 (the client you cannot change) as the actual server while it just inject requests into the queuing server. You will also have to use 2 queues.

For clarity, let's enumerate the system players:

- The client
- The proxy server, a server that offers the same API offered by the actual (but it doesn't do any work)
- The actual server, the server that does the actual work
- The input queue, the queue where clients requests go into (proxy server does that)
- The output queue, the queue where server responses go into (actual server does that)

A possible working scenario:

- A client sends a request to the proxy server
- The proxy server puts the request in input queue
- The actual server (listening to the input queue) will fetch the request
- The actual server process the message
- The actual server sends the response to the output queue
- The proxy server (listening to the output queue) will fetch the response
- The proxy server returns the response to the client

This might work, but few problems could happen, e.g. because the proxy server doesn't know when the actual server will response, and, it cannot be sure of the order of responses in the output queue, it may have to re-inject the messages it finds not relevant to the output queue until it finds the correct message.

Or, the proxy server might need to feed the response to the client later via an HTTP request to the client. That is, rather than a response to the client's request, the client will expect no response for the request it sent knowing that it will be get the answer later via a request from the proxy server.

I'm not aware of the situation at your end, but this might work!